# Can't RemoteDesktop into my PC from outside the network

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

My network at home is pretty simple, an Xfinity wireless modem/router that I connect my desktop and laptop to. In this configuration the laptop can remote to the desktop.

But if the laptop is elsewhere, and needs to remote in over the network, then it fails with the standard message (Windows 10). "Remote desktop can't connect ..."

From inside the network the laptop can connect using the external IP address so that tells me it should work when remote.

Comment: You need first to connect with your home network with VPN that allow you to see the home network IP addresses from outside. I do this with IPsec VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. From [this page](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-remove-desktop-app-connect-pc-windows-10-0) - had to do part II **also**. Here are the instructions (the link has screenshots too which helps):

Settings app
You must **also** enable the Remote Desktop feature using the Settings app with these steps:

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on System.
3. Click on Remote Desktop.
4. Turn on the Enable Remote Desktop toggle switch.
5. Click the Confirm button.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to RDP to the external ip-address from inside doesn't mean anything. That could be just weird behavior from your router.

Did you setup port-forwarding on your router to map the RDP traffic (port 3389) to your desktop?
If not you will first have to do that.

If that is done and it still doesn't work there are 2 possibilities:

1. Your provider does carrier-grade NAT. Meaning your external ip-address is shared between you and other of their customers. In that case you just can't host the RDP service at all.
2. Your provider blocks RDP access. In that case it won't work either.

If you get it to work: Exposing RDP to the Internet is a really stupid thing to do. Every script-kiddy in the world will try to log in to your RDP. Your router and desktop will be hammered by attempts to brute-force the password for the RDP session.
You will also be vulnerable to every exploit found in the RDP protocol (there have been several in the past).
If too many attempts per second are made the RDP service will actually shutdown to protect itself (locking you out) and will need to be restarted manually. (This a sort-of better-than-nothing safety that Microsoft added to the Windows RDP service some years ago.)

If you really need remote control when you are on the road consider a solution like TeamViewer. That doesn't require special router config and will work with ISP's that block RDP or that use carrier-grade NAT.
Or setup a proper VPN solution (unless your ISP does carrier-grade NAT again, NAT is a showstopper for anything that requires an incoming conenction).